# Should I bring my dog with us to a Cabin

Tags: camping, dogs

Recently my girlfriend and I were invited to go camping with our friends at a cabin in Flagstaff, Arizona. My buddies have already left and we're supposed to  leave tomorrow to go and meet them up there. Everything has worked out great so far... except for one thing.... I want to bring my dog.
Now I'm sure your wondering what the issue is, and well my friends have already left and took their dog with them. Now both theirs and mine know each other very well for they have played together during SEVERAL bbq's, so thats not going to be a problem. The problem we are currently facing is apparently if my dog goes, according to my girlfriend, that my friends will have to tie up their dog while ours is there where as if I just leave her home their dog can "run free" so to speak. Now I can honnestly see their point in the sense of the two dogs playing and getting carried away and taking off twoard another cabin. But outside of that? I don't personally see a problem and I seriously doubt they would do it, but you never know...
This is the first time I have gone camping in YEARS and its most certanally the first time since I've had my dog... I don't think its fair to just leave her home like my girl seems to think so.... We do live in an apartment where she doesn't get out as much as she should, but she DOES get out. We can't take her to the dog park because of her breed, despite the fact she is friendly. She gets to go for walks and about once a week to once every two weeks she gets to go and run free on a 2 acre property until lays down in a heap of happy tails and belly rubs. She does really well as far as listening goes when on this property, but thorw in another dog and she doesnkt listen as well as she should, to be honnest sometimes I have to call her multiple times. sometimes I don't. just depends. So please, I'm asking for your advice, should I bring her or should I leave her?

My Dog:
Breed: Pitbull Boxer Mix
Age: 3 Years.
Sex: Female
Personality: Loving, Sweet Adhd Hyper, protective will probably run circles around the cabin for at LEAST 30 minuets when we get there.

Their Dog:
Breed: Brindle lab mix
Age: 4 years?
Sex: Male
Personality: Loving, sweet, protective, at times adhd hyper and will probably run circles around the cabin with my dog once/if she gets there.

How many people total there:
4 adults.
3 kids (6, 7, and 9)
and 1 dog for sure.

How many days:
For my friends: a week
For us: Two Nights and two and a quarter days.

EDIT: I would just like to add that if we leave the dog, the dog will NOT be neglected. I have a cat as well who needs to be fed and given attention to. We have someone who is going to be stopping by the house to spend time with the cat/make it seem like someone is home. The main reasons why my girl does not want to take the dog are because we recently have gotten knew neighbors within the last week, we're pretty sure the people beside us do drugs and we don't want to risk our things stolen and in her mind the dog would scare intruders away (yes i have pointed out that if they REALLY want in, they could kill or harm her) and the last reason, she doesn't want to have to worry about said dog doing something she's not supposed to. I'm confident in her, but my fiance is not with another dog around.

I need to know opinions soon, we're leaving tomorrow (8-26-14) evening.

Comment: Hi Rayne, and welcome to [Outdoors.SE].  It would be great if you could edit your question to make it more general, so it focusses more clearly on aspects that might help future visitors!

Comment: Didn't vote for a close yet but @Rayne please make the question more structured, readable and especially **shorter**.

Comment: Hi Rayne - there really isn't a definitive answer here, so have added my close vote as 'opinion-based'. I toyed with migrating to pets.SE, but it would still be opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if one dog has to be tied up and they are worried about them being too boisterous, why not have yours tied up? In most campsites in England (I know it is different where you are) dogs have to be on leads and tied up at all times.

If you plan on future trips with your friends, eventually she will have to go. If you follow the always on a lead rule to begin with, she will get used to it over time. Then you can let her off the lead for longer periods until it is no longer 'new' to her.

It might be an idea to train her so she is a little less hyper and more willing to follow commands around other dogs. She is still young and is more than capable of learning.

Alternatively, assuming you have a sitter for your dog, you are not going for that long. You can always skip taking her this time, and if a trip happens again talk to your friends before going. Have them spend more time together if possible so they don't become so enthused at having a play friend. Then if you go on holiday together again it shouldn't be a problem.

I cannot give a definitive answer saying yes or no, it is ultimately your choice. I can only give my views and experience on the situation. I used to train hearing dogs to be less enthused at seeing other dogs, it can be done with a little patience.

We recently took a chocolate lab puppy on her first camping trip, my other half asked a question about camping with her, and this was the suggested answer: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/5902/3673

Answer (score 2):

Leaving a dog alone in an apartment for this length of time would be neglectful, even if you were able to provide enough food and water.

Your girlfriend's logic doesn't make sense to me. Just having your dog there doesn't imply that the other dog has to be tied up.

I would bring a long rope for your own dog and evaluate the situation once you get there in order to decide whether it's OK to let her run free. Discuss it with your friends when you get there. Figure out if there are roads with high-speed traffic, or livestock. Figure out if there are fences that will limit your dog's movement. If your friends are familiar with the area and normally let their dog run free, then that tells you it's probably going to be OK, but your standards for safety might be different from theirs, or your dog's tendency to run away might be different from theirs.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly. I think this should have been addressed with your friends and/or the campsite/resort.
If you know all this and the 2 dogs get along then, take your dog.
The worse that will happen is that your, or both, dogs will have to be leashed.
I honestly don't see how this should be a community question because every campground, resort, or just someone's cabin has their own set of rules and/or guidelines as to bringing animals.